# How can I filter a Flux using the value of a Mono that I get per Flux element?

Tags: spring, spring-webflux, project-reactor

Let's say I have a `Flux<User>` and another `Mono<Department>`. `Department` has and id and departmentName.

I have a service that returns the Department a User belongs to:

```
departmentService.getByUserId(userId: Int) : Mono<Department>
```

I want to filter users that aren't in a Department (`departmentService.getByUserId(userId: Int)` returns an empty Mono) or are in a Department whose departmentName is not HR. How can this be done?

```
users.flatMap { user ->
    departMentService.getByUserId(user.id)
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My solution consisted on using Pair to propagate an aggregation of the information I needed in the filter:

```
users.flatMap { user ->
    departMentService.getByUserId(user.id)
       .map { Pair(user, it) }
}.filter { it.second == null || it.second.departmentName != "HR" }
```